# Powershell TCP Send and Receive response

Tags: powershell, tcplistener

I am using a PowerShell TCP listener accept a connection then send and receive over that connection.

I need to send:

```
$Ret = 0x02 + [string]"LS$(Current)" + 0x03
```

So an `0x02` start and `0x03` end but I cannot get it into a variable to use a:

```
$writer.Write($Ret)
$writer.Flush()
```

To transmit it over TCP

Any suggestions would help.

```
#Current function
Function Current {
    $Now = Get-Date -format "yy:MM:dd:HH:mm:ss"
    $IM = $Now -split ":"
    $P1 = "|DA" + $IM[0] + $IM[1] + $IM[2]
    $P2 = "|TI" + $IM[3] + $IM[4] + $IM[5] + "|"
    $P3 = $P1 + $P2
    Return $P3
}

$continue = $true
$port = 8471
$IPEndPoint = New-Object System.Net.IPEndPoint([IPAddress]::Any,$port)
$listener = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener $IPEndPoint
$listener.Start()

[Byte] $B1 = 0x02
[Byte] $B2 = 0x03

while ($continue -eq $true) {
    $data = $Null
    $client = $listener.AcceptTcpClient()
    $rEndpoint = $client.client.RemoteEndPoint
    $stream = $Client.GetStream()
    $client.NoDelay = $True

    #Stream Prep
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $stream
    $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $Stream
    $writer.AutoFlush = $true

    If($client.Connected -eq $false) {
        "Not Connected"
    }

    $buffer = new-object System.byte[] 1024
    $EncodedText = new-object System.Text.AsciiEncoding 

    If ($client.Connected -and $Count -lt 1) {
        $R1 = "LS$(Current)" 
        $Ret = 0x02 + [string]"LS$(Current)" + 0x03
        $writer.Write($Ret)
        $writer.Flush()
        Write-Host $Ret
        $Count++
    }   

    while ($client.Connected -and $stream.DataAvailable -and ($i = $stream.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)) -ne 0) {
        $data += $EncodedText.GetString($buffer, 0, $i)
        $stream.Flush()
    }        

    If($Data -eq $null) {
        $Data = $Reader.ReadLine()
    }

    Write-Host "$rEndpoint`: $data"  
    # Get-Variable -Name data 

    If($data -eq "StopIt") {
        $stream.Close()
        $client.Close()
        $continue = $false
        $listener.stop()
        $Client.Close()
        $stream.Close()
        $listener.stop()
        $reader.Close()
        $writer.Close()
    } ElseIf($data -match "LS") {
        $Ret = "'\x02LS$(Current)\x03'"
        $writer.WriteLine($Ret)
        Write-Host $Ret
    } ElseIf($data -match "x02LA") {
        $Ret = "\x02LA$(Current)\x03"
        $writer.Write($Ret)
        Write-Host $Ret
    } ElseIf($Data -eq $Null) {
        $Data
        "Not"
        # $Ret = "'\x02LS$(Current)\x03'"
        # $writer.WriteLine($Ret)
        # Write-Host $Ret
    } ElseIf($Data -match "DR") {
        $Data
        Write-host "DR Request"
        # Resenc query to database
    } ElseIf($Data -match "PS") {
        $Data
        Write-host "PS Request"
        # Room paid query
    } Else {
        $Data
        Write-host "Other Request"
    }

    $Reader.Close()   
    $writer.Close()
    $stream.Close()
    $client.Close()
    start-sleep -Milliseconds 500
}
```

In Python it looks like this:

```py
s = 'LS|DA220601|TI195645|'
m = b'\x02' + s.encode('ascii') + b'\x03'
```

Need to send the same thing over a TCP connection with PowerShell.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: `0x02 + [string]"LS$(Current)" + 0x03` is surely going to fail because the string `LSXXX` can't possibly be meaningfully converted to a number. You'll want something like `$ret = @(0x2;$EncodedText.GetBytes("LS$(Current)");0x3) -as [byte[]]` instead

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so that converts it all to hex.  I need the middle part to stay a string, this is the current outbut; "2 76 83 124 68 65 50 50 48 54 48 50 124 84 73 48 56 51 51 50 54 124 3"  but it needs to return something like this "2|DA220602|TI083418|3"

Comment: In python it looks like this;  s = 'LS|DA220601|TI195645|'
m = b'\x02' + s.encode('ascii') + b'\x03' - needto return the same in powershell.  Any ideas? Thanks Peter

Comment: You need to @ him so he can see your response. @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen In python it looks like this; s = 'LS|DA220601|TI195645|' m = b'\x02' + s.encode('ascii') + b'\x03' - needto return the same in powershell. Any ideas? Thanks for the reply, so that converts it all to hex. I need the middle part to stay a string, this is the current outbut; "2 76 83 124 68 65 50 50 48 54 48 50 124 84 73 48 56 51 51 50 54 124 3" but it needs to return something like this "2|DA220602|TI083418|3"

Comment: As I see it, `s.encode('ascii')` in Python is the same as `[Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($s)` in PowerShell, which is what Mathias pointed out before.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, yes but it put is all in bytes. Only the start and end ar bytes the middel need to be a string as I understand it, it is something called the  FIAS 2.20.23 API spec from Oracle i am trying to communicate with .$ret = @(0x02;$EncodedText.GetBytes("LS$(Current)");0x03) -as [byte[]] - returns 2 76 83 124 68 65 50 50 48 54 48 50 124 84 73 49 49 52 52 52 48 124 3  Thanks Peter

Answer (score 0):

```
$port=8471
$IPEndPoint=New-Object System.Net.IPEndPoint([IPAddress]::Any,$port)
$listener = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener $IPEndPoint
$listener.Start()    
$data = $Null
$client = $listener.AcceptTcpClient()
$rEndpoint = $client.client.RemoteEndPoint
$client.NoDelay = $True
$PS=$Client.GetStream()
@((0x02) -as [byte[]];$([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($Ret));(0x03) -as 
byte[]])
$PS.Write($data1,0,$data1.Length)
$PS.Flush()
```

The above fixed it. Thanksall.
Peter